# Is it possible to create a loop that searches all the files in a directory and display the one that I want?

Tags: shell-script

Is there a way to create a script with an if loop to search in a directory and gather all the files by displaying them? Then I want the the user to select the file and view them.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop". Do you mean a "for loop" or a "while loop"?

Comment: sorry made a huge mistake I meant a for loop.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope no need of `for` loop. try this,

```
DIRECTORY_PATH=/path/to/dir
FILE_LIST=(`ls -p $DIRECTORY_PATH | grep -v / `)
printf '%s\n' "${FILE_LIST[@]}" | nl -v 1
read -r -p "please enter index number to open: " fileNO
cat $DIRECTORY_PATH/${FILE_LIST[$fileNO]}
```

- `FILE_LIST` list only files in the given directory
- `printf` to list the array of files one by one
- `nl` number each line
- `read` to get the runtime input
- finally, `cat` the file by indexing the array

Comment: In the "FILE_LIST=(`ls -p $DIRECTORY_PATH | grep -v / `)" the grep -v / what is used for because on mine it's not showing any files whatsoever. Moreover because of the n1 in the 3rd line, pop ups saying command not found. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `ls -p` will display all directory with trailing `/` , so we are ignoring those directory names.

Comment: its `nl` (L)  not `n1`

Comment: FILE_LIST=(`ls -p $DIRECTORY_PATH | grep -v / `) does this command still work with txt/nano documents since that's what i need it for?